# Visual Studio .csproj file have a "TargetFramework" variable

Tags: visual-studio, wix, csproj

I updated some of my .csproj file from the old format to the new .csproj format, so as to be able to provide multiple target frameworks.

This broke the wix installer builder, because the TargetPath variable was no longer available.
I implemented the workaround here: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5705

```
    <Target Name="GetTargetPath" Returns="@(_Net40OutputPath)">
        <ItemGroup>
            <_Net40OutputPath Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(PackageOutputPath)\net40\$(AssemblyName).dll" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
```

You can see that I am using variables for every value except for the `TargetFramework`. I am forced to hardcode `net40` because I am unaware of a variable I can use.

Is there a way I can determine the output path of the project entirely by variables?